# Programming an app for a beacon

Tags: android, beacon

I have a minibeacon bluetooth and I would like to create an android application to locate its position. The troube is that I don't know how to proceed, how to insert the beacon's uuid in the source code?
I would be very glad if someone can help me to resolve this or give me some source code or someone who has experienced this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

On Android you do not need to know the beacon's UUID or other identifier.  You can simply scan for all beacons and read the identifier of whichever you find that is closest.

You can see sample code for ranging with the Android Beacon Library here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: Thank  you very much indeed